# $ \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \left(\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan x \right)^x$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 3^+} \frac{\cos x \ln(x-3)}{\ln(e^x-e^3)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

> I got stuck on two exercises below
>   $$
> \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \left(\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan x \right)^x   \\
> \lim_{x\rightarrow 3^+} \frac{\cos x  \ln(x-3)}{\ln(e^x-e^3)}
> $$

For the first one , let $y=(\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan x )^x $, so $\ln y =x\ln (\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan x )$, the right part is $\infty \cdot 0$ type, but seemly, the L 'hopital's rule is useless.  PS: I know the $\infty \cdot 0$ can be become to $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$. But when I use the L 'hopital's rule to the $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\frac{0}{0}$ the calculation is complex and useless.

For the second one , it is $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ type, also useless the L 'hopital's rule is. How to calculate it ?

Comment: For $0\times\infty$ types, you can algebraically transform them into either $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, where you can try using L'Hopital's (though it may not help): just remember that $ab = \frac{a}{\ \frac{1}{b}\ }$. And, L'Hopital's Rule **is** applicable for $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ indeterminates...

Comment: Try to avoid asking several questions in a single post. If you feel that the answer would be similar, ask about the first limit, and then try to solve the second one by yourself, and if you are still stuck, ask a separate question. The software has a limit on how many questions you can ask in a single day, and doing it like this is circumventing these limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the first one using

- $\arctan x + \operatorname{arccot}x = \frac{\pi}{2}$
- $\lim_{y\to 0}(1-y)^{1/y} = e^{-1}$
- $x\operatorname{arccot}x \stackrel{\stackrel{x =\cot u}{u\to 0^+}}{=} \cot u\cdot u = \cos u\cdot \frac{u}{\sin u} \stackrel{u \to 0^+}{\longrightarrow} 1$

\begin{eqnarray*} \left(\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan x \right)^x
& \stackrel{\arctan x = \frac{\pi}{2}-\operatorname{arccot}x}{=} & \left( \underbrace{\left(1- \frac{2}{\pi}\operatorname{arccot}x\right)^{\frac{\pi}{2\operatorname{arccot}x}}}_{\stackrel{x \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} e^{-1}} \right)^{\frac{2}{\pi}\underbrace{x\operatorname{arccot}x}_{\stackrel{x \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} 1}} \\
& \stackrel{x \to +\infty}{\longrightarrow} & e^{-\frac{2}{\pi}}
\end{eqnarray*}

The second limit is quite straight forward as $\lim_{x\to 3+}\cos x = \cos 3$. Just consider

- $\frac{\ln(x-3)}{\ln(e^x-e^3)}$ and apply L'Hospital.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite $\infty\cdot 0$ as $\infty \cdot \dfrac{1}{\infty}$. Now you can apply L'Hopital's rule: $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{\left(\ln 2/\pi\cdot\arctan x \right)}{1/x}=\lim_{x\to +\infty}\dfrac{\pi/2\cdot \arctan x}{-1/x^2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{1+x^2}=-\dfrac{\pi }{2}\lim_{x\to +\infty}\arctan x\cdot \dfrac{x^2}{1+x^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Without L'Hospital
$$y=\left(\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan (x) \right)^x\implies \log(y)=x \log\left(\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan (x) \right)  $$

Now, by Taylor for large values of $x$
$$\arctan (x)=\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{3 x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$
$$\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan (x) =1-\frac{2}{\pi  x}+\frac{2}{3 \pi  x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$$ Taylor again
$$\log\left(\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan (x) \right)= -\frac{2}{\pi  x}-\frac{2}{\pi ^2 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$
$$\log(y)=x\log\left(\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan (x) \right)= -\frac{2}{\pi  }-\frac{2}{\pi ^2 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ Just continue with Taylor using $y=e^{\log(y)}$ if you want to see not only the limit but also how it is approached

Answer (score 0):

For the first: taking $\log$ and doing the cov $x = 1/t$ and using L'Hôpital:
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}x\log\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan x \right) =
\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac 1t\log\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\arctan(1/t)\right) =
\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac {-1}{(t^2 + 1)\arctan(1/t))} = -\frac 2\pi.
$$